# ASP.NET MVC and IE cache/Temporary internet file folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Our MVC based Call center application is heavily used one, at least for 8 to 9 hours continuously on stretch by accessing different functionalities/pages available on the application. Application heavily uses partialviews  on many places which inturn has 3rd party infragisitcs grid. After an hour of usage,  IE Temporary internet file folder get filled up and application starts throwing up below javascript issue

**Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.**

On clearing IE cache/Temporary internet file folder application behaves normally for another hour or so then again same above javascript error start appearing until you again clear IE cache/Temporary internet file folder.

Is this normal behavior of ASP.NET MVC based application or we missing something in terms of implementation? Any permanent kind of fix/work around to get rid of the situation?

Comment: No, this is not normal MVC behavior. There is something specific to your application causing the temporary internet files to fill up. But posting this question here without giving us any idea what types of files are filing up all of the space is not going to get you an answer.

Comment: .html type of files filing up temp internet file folder. As mentioned in my above query, my application composing view using many partail views & these partial views contain definition for jquery based infragistics grid. So when user action request for view which contains partail views all these partial views are downloded in the form of .html files which in turn fill up temp internet file folder.